# When do I need to have a preposition before whether?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I often see prepositions that come before *whether* and I feel that most of the time these prepositions are unnecessary.

> I'm confused **as to** whether a preposition is required before *whether*.
>
> I haven't decided **on** whether to put a preposition before *whether*.
>
> I don't know **about** whether a preposition is required before *whether*.

The times where I feel a preposition is preferred involve a noun coming before *whether*.

> There's no news **as to** whether Jane will show up to today's meeting.
>
> We haven't received an update **on** whether the party will arrive on time.

Is a preposition ever required before whether? If so, what are the circumstances where one would have to use a preposition before whether?

Comment: It's normal to include a preposition *(as to, regarding, about, etc.)* between ***confused*** and whatever causes the confusion, but no preposition is usually included after ***decide, know, choose***, etc.

Comment: As FumbleFingers says, it is not about "whether": it is entirely about the word or phrase of which the "whether" clause is a complement, and what kind of complements that word or phrase requires or allows.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Would it be "normal" in the linguistic world to say it depends on the *affordances* of the preceding clause?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't recall seeing that word used, but I'm years behind in my reading ;-)  The phrase I would use is its _subcategorisation frame_.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I'll take that as a "No" then! :) I'm not trying to be a trailblazer here - if I could fluently use whatever terminology you're familiar with I'd be more than satisfied (and I know that's a *seriously* "irrealis" hypothetical! :)

Answer (score 1):

In all of your examples it's the preceding phrase, not the word *whether,* that controls the following word(s):

***I'm confused as to whether a preposition is required before whether.***
I'm confused as to the nature of your question.
I'm confused how often I need to ask the question. (I'd prefer *confused about,* but *about* is commonly omitted in practice, especially informally.)

***I haven't decided on whether to put a preposition before whether.***
I haven't decided on a dress to wear.
I haven't decided to take the job.

***I don't know about whether a preposition is required before whether.***
I don't know about history.
I don't know biology.
(In your sentence, I'd always omit *about.*)

***There's no news as to whether Jane will show up to today's meeting.***
There's no news as to the outcome of the election.
There's no news concerning the baby.

***We haven't received an update on whether the party will arrive on time.***
We haven't received an update on your progress.
We haven't received an update to the software.
(We always receive updates *on* or *to* things. *On* means "about a topic." *To* means the thing has been changed.)

Comment: More specifically, it's the predicate in the preceding clause that determines just about everything about its complement clauses. _Whether_ is just one more complementizer, like _what, where, that, for, to,_ etc, and simply identifies the type of complement, guided by the affordances and prohibitions of each individual predicate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the use of **whether or not** that determines the need for a preposition, but the word before that preposition.

---

*The phrase "as to" in the following sentence is used because of "confused," although it may be omitted.*

I'm confused as to whether a preposition is required before whether.

---

*The preposition "on" is in this sentence because of "decided."*

I haven't decided on whether to put a preposition before whether.

---

*The preposition "about" is in this sentence because of "know," although it may be omitted and not change the essence of the sentence.*

I don't know about whether a preposition is required before whether.

---

*In the sentence below, "as to" may be omitted and still have with a meaningful sentence.*

There's no news as to whether Jane will show up to today's meeting.

---

*In this sentence, "on" is there because of "update."*

We haven't received an update on whether the party will arrive on time.